# Data retrieval from multiple objects from a single query

Tags: soql

I have just started understanding SOQL. I am trying to query to retrieve data from multiple object.

I have below objects and junction objects:

[image]

I want to display unique records of Object 3 based on the value of Object 1 ID.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a query that you worked on? Please post more info where you stuck on your implementation, that way we can help you out.

Answer (score 4):

You're allowed to go "down" one level of relationship, and up to five. Accordingly, we can make a "W" shaped query by starting from "Object 2". That query would look like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT Obj1__r.Name FROM Junction1__r),
       (SELECT Obj3__r.Name FROM Junction2__r),
       Name
FROM Obj2__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Obj2__c FROM Junction1__c WHERE Obj1__c = 'some-id-here')
```

Note that this is all hypothetical, you'll need to puzzle out the correct relationship/field/object names.